# ¿como borrar un solo row y archivo de un listview?

Tags: java, android

Necesito borrar un archivo de un listView. El listview es alimentado por medio de archivos xml que esta guardados en la memoria. ¿como puedo borrar el row del listView y que también borre el archivo xml? con este codigo puedo borrar pero se borran todos y no se borra el archivo XML.

```
      CustomList listAdapter = new
                    CustomList(OFActivityA.this, ficheros,fecha);
            list2=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
            list2.setAdapter(listAdapter)

          list2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position,    long id) {


            String item = ficheros[+ position];

            list.remove(item);

            list2.setAdapter(null);

                }
            });



 List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();


    public void listarFicherosPorCarpeta(final File carpeta) {
        for (final File ficheroEntrada: carpeta.listFiles()) {

            if (ficheroEntrada.isDirectory()) {
                listarFicherosPorCarpeta(ficheroEntrada);
            } else {
                System.out.println(ficheroEntrada.getName());

                  list.add(ficheroEntrada.getName());
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Revisa [ask] para que puedas formular una pregunta que sea aceptada por la comunidad. Muestra lo que has intentado.

Comment: olvide el codigo disculpa

Answer (score 0):

Usa la posicion para borrar el item, luego usa el metodo `notifyItemRemove()` y mandas como parametro la posicion que recibes en el `onItemClick`, hay posibilidad de que te salga algun error, si es asi usa `notifyItemRangeChanged()` que es como una especie de listener cuando algo en la lista cambie, te debe quedar algo asi

```
        list.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(posicion, list.size());
```

Comment: Me sale el rojo el metodo, no lo reconoce